# How to find table using beautifulsoup without a name? For python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to find the third table from the website http://indexarb.com/index.html. but i cant find the table's unique name.

the valueim trying to get the text in the first column:
"S&P 500 Prem greater than 1.49"

Can you guys please help?

```
url = requests.get("http://indexarb.com/index.html")

html_content = url.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "html.parser")
soup = soup.find_all("table")
print(soup)
```

Comment: If you look at the html for this question you'll see that it is rather more complicated. Are you sure that question is sufficiently similar?

Comment: The question is not similar idk why it was marked that way

Comment: The table you want is nested quite deeply and it would be easier to use xpath to get at it: `import lxml.html; root = lxml.html.fromstring(requests.get(..).content); t=root.xpath('/html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr/td[3]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table'); print t[0].text_content().encode('l1')` You could use BS on the last value if you wanted to..

Comment: thank you so much thebjorn, that helped, I will be using xpaths going forward :)